# JavaScript: confusion about the callback passed in to `addEventListener`

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a question about JavaScript's native `addEventListener`, normally we are using it like `js selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => { const value =   event.target.value });`

but today I was looking at the type definition for it in TypeScript, it says the callback we pass into the `addEventListener` has this signature

```
(this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any
```

so the first param it takes is actually an `html` element. I am a bit confused as we normally treat the first param as an event object as in my first example there.

Comment: "*the first param it takes is actually an html element*" no, it's a description of the `this` value, not a parameter it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is small example:

```js
class B {
  handleB() { }
}
class A {
  // I have defined [B] as a this/context of callback
  add(callback: (this: B, ev: number) => void) { }
}

const result = new A();

result.add(function (el) { // el -> number
  const x = this.handleB // TS thinks that [this] of this function is [B]. 

})
```

More information about typing `this` You can find [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. it is kinda interesting that in plain javascript if I write this `
async function handleChange(this) {}` I would get an error for `Unexpected keyword 'this'` but in TypeScript that would be acceptable... Do you know what caused the difference here?

Comment: Because when you wtite THIS in TS, it is like defining a context of callback. You should not treat it as an argument. It is similar how you define SELF in python or rust

Answer (score 2):

> so the first param it takes is actually an html element.

No. It says that [the **this** value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) is an HTML element.

```js
function handler(event) {
    console.log("this", this instanceof HTMLElement);
    console.log("event", event instanceof Event);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handler);
```

```html
<button>Content</button>
```

Note that [arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable) use a lexical this instead of a contextual one so that won't work if you use an arrow function like your first example.

Comment: thanks... so does the `this` get implicitly passed to the function? this is just the why how TS annotates `this` value's type `(this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any`?